# Return the average mark givin the respective lecture

Tags: python, list, whitespace

Each line represents a single student and consists of a student number, a name, a section code and a midterm grade, all separated by whitespace.
The first parameter is already done and the file is open and
The second parameter is a section code
this is the link http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~csc108h/fall/exercises/e3/grade_file.txt

My code:

```
def average_by_section(the_file, section_code):  
    '''(io.TextIOWrapper, str) -> float  
    Return the average midtermmark for all students in that section  
    '''  
        score = 0  
        n = 0  
        for element in the_file:  
            line = element.split()  
            if section_code == line[-2]:  
                mark = mark + float(line[-1])  
                n += 1  

        lecture_avg = mark / n  
        return lecture_avg
```

I'm getting an index out of range. Is this correct? Or am I just opening up the wrong file?
can someone test this code and download that file? I'm pretty sure it should work, but not for me.

Comment: Is `score` supposed to be `mark` (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can troubleshoot the index out of range error with a  `print line` or `print(line)` to explore the number of items in "line" (i.e. the effect of `split()`). I'd suggest looking closer at your `split()` statement...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are omitting parts of your code where you define some of those variables (`section_code`, `mark`, etc.), but adjusting for some of those things seems to work properly. Assuming that the error you got was `IndexError: list index out of range`, that happens when you try to access an element of a list by index where that index doesn't exist. For instance:

```
>>> l = ['one']
>>> l[0]
'one'
>>> l[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>> l[-1]
'one'
>>> l[-2]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Therefore in your code, you will get that error if `line` is ever fewer than two items. I would check and see what you are actually getting for `line` to make sure it is what you expect.